# Getkey and value by Except on just value

Tags: c#, linq

I start with a Dictionary<string,string>(), and want to remove from it entries whose Values exist in another List<string>.  The following code just returns a List. Can Except somehow return a Dictionary of the remaining key/value pairs after removing matching values?  If not, how could this be done?

```
//pardon my pseudocode
var pNames = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {key : "a1", value: "asdf_a1"},
    {key : "a2", value: "asdf_a2"},
    {key : "a3", value: "asdf_a3"}
};

var bUsers = new List<string>() { "asdf_a2" };

var nUsers = pNames.Values.Except(bUsers);
//nUsers should be a Dictionary<string,string> containing two key/value pairs:
//{key : "a1", value: "asdf_a1"},
//{key : "a3", value: "asdf_a3"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want a new dictionary, as opposed to removing items from the existing one, you can filter the `KeyValuePair<string,string>` objects that make up the dictionary using `Where` and then use the `ToDictionary` extension method to convert the resulting `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` back into a `Dictionary<string,string>`.

```
var nUsers = pNames
    .Where(pn => !bUsers.Contains(pn.Value)) // This will be IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

If you want a case insensitive match, add an `IEqualityComparer<string>` as a second argument to the `Contains` method.

Answer (score 0):

Tried and tested

```
Dictionary<string, string> pNames = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
    {"a1", "asdf_a1"},
    {"a2", "asdf_a2"},
    {"a3", "asdf_a3"}
};

var bUsers = new List<string>() { "asdf_a2" };

bUsers.ForEach(user => 
{
    var Names = pNames.Where(name => name.Value == user).ToList();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> Name in Names)
        pNames.Remove(Name.Key);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect. but You could something similar. the benefit of this approach is that you can use with anytype.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> pNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        pNames.Add("a1", "value1");
        pNames.Add("a2", "value2");
        var bUsers = new List<string>() { "value1" };

        var newKey = bUsers.ToDictionary(idx =>
        {
            return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }, x => x);

        var result = pNames.Except(newKey, new CustomIEqualityComparer<string, string>());
    }

    public class CustomIEqualityComparer<TSource, TValue> : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<TSource, TValue>>
    {
        public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<TSource, TValue> x, KeyValuePair<TSource, TValue> y)
        {
            return x.Value.Equals(y.Value);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<TSource, TValue> obj)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = 17;
                hash = hash * 23 + obj.Value.GetHashCode();
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use with `<int, string>` type then it will be the same code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static int index = 0;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> pNames = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        pNames.Add(1, "value1");
        pNames.Add(2, "value2");
        var bUsers = new List<string>() { "value1" };

        var newKey = bUsers.ToDictionary(idx =>
        {
            return index++;
        }, x => x);

        var result = pNames.Except(newKey, new CustomIEqualityComparer<int, string>());
    }

    public class CustomIEqualityComparer<TSource, TValue> : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<TSource, TValue>>
    {
        public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<TSource, TValue> x, KeyValuePair<TSource, TValue> y)
        {
            return x.Value.Equals(y.Value);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<TSource, TValue> obj)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = 17;
                hash = hash * 23 + obj.Value.GetHashCode();
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can further refine and improve.